# pandas rename: change values of index for a specific column only

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
                   Cost
Year  Month  ID  
2016  1      10    40
      2      11    50
2017  4      1     60
```

The columns `Year`, `Month` and `ID` make up the index. I want to set the values within `Month` to be the name equivalent (e.g. 1 = Jan, 2 = Feb). I've come up with the following code:

```
df.rename(index={i: calendar.month_abbr[i] for i in range(1, 13)}, inplace=True)
```

However, this changes the values within every column in the index:

```
                   Cost
Year  Month  ID  
2016  Jan    10    40
      Feb    11    50
2017  Apr    Jan   60    # Jan here is incorrect
```

I obviously only want to change the values in the Month column. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `set_levels`

```
m = {1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 4: 'Mar'}
df.index.set_levels(
    df.index.levels[1].to_series().map(m).values,
    1, inplace=True)

print(df)

               Cost
Year Month ID      
2016 Jan   10    40
     Feb   11    50
2017 Mar   1     60
```

Comment: Where is my dictionary mapping number to abbr? Is that `m`?

Comment: Last question: If I have an 'All' row at the bottom, the cell for that row / column I'm editing becomes `NaN`. Any way I can avoid this?

Comment: @jcmetz21 is `All` in the same level as the month numbers?

Comment: No I'm building a pivot table so `All` is the `margin=True` row at the end

Comment: I'd just use `'All': 'All'` in the mapping dictionary.

Comment: You're the man! Just had to add `'':''` to the mapping dict (`NaN` was next to `All`). Thanks again

Comment: Last question I promise! How can I get the index level from just the index column name. For example, here I need the level number of `'Month'` (which we know is 1) - I want to dynamically change these index values based on name

Comment: You should ask that as a question.  You'll get more rep.  Someone who answers will get more up-votes.  Good for everyone.  Also, I don't know at the moment and am trying to figure it out.

Comment: Just figured it out: `pt.index.names.index('Month')` returns `1`. Otherwise I would definitely post

Comment: I forgot `list` has an index... awesome :-)  I just did `np.searchsorted(pt.index.names, 'Month')`